# Hash function that maps to +-1

Tags: python, random, hash

I'm trying to generate a random hash function in python that maps every element in a list (without a known range) to {-1,1} and I'm a struggling.

I found np.random.choice that answers the range of the mapping (+-1), but it might not map the same element to the same value (it isn't an hash function).
How can I do this right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the regular `hash` function and return `-1` if it's an odd number and `1` otherwise…?

Comment: I don't know if it will be as stable as you want but maybe you can use `functools.lru_cache` to keep an already computed result in memory.

Comment: `1 - 2 * (super_wonderful_hash(x) & 1)`, as stated by @deceze

Comment: @abc123: How persistent is the "same element to same value" restriction? Should it apply across machines? Across platforms? Across different processes on the same machine? Across different sessions on a single machine? And what are the types of the list elements? Strings? Numbers? Other more interesting types?

Comment: If you want to be consistent across different machines then don't use any built-in hash functions.  Instead use a specific function such as [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) which will be consistent across different architectures.